# ava: SyntaxError: Unexpected token import

Tags: ava

So ava comes with [build-in ES2015 support](https://github.com/sindresorhus/ava#es2015-support), which works fine for my actual test files. However, when I do

```
import {newUser, createUser, login} from './helpers/user';
```

I can't use `import` and export in the helper file, I then get:

```
Users/rowe/Code/fv/foxvision-api/test/api/helpers/user.js:1
(function (exports, require, module, __filename, __dirname) { import request from 'supertest';

SyntaxError: Unexpected token import
```

I have no specific babel configuration set up as for the test files it works out of the box. Can anyone explain to me why the helper dependencies are not transpiled with babel? Using `test/**/helpers` is even following [ava convention](https://github.com/sindresorhus/ava#cli).

Thanks,
Robin

**Solution**

So based on [thangngoc89](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3976412/thangngoc89)'s solution, what I did to make it work was:

1. Add a `.babelrc` with content:

```js
{
  "presets": [
    "es2015",
    "stage-2"
  ],
  "plugins": [
    "espower",
    "transform-runtime"
  ]
}
```

2. Added to `package.json`:

```js
"ava": {
  "require": ["babel-register"],
  "babel": "inherit"
}
```

Comment: the `"require": ["babel-register"],` in package.json is necessary even though http://babeljs.io/docs/setup/#installation doesn't mention it.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

AVA only transpile the test files. Not test dependencies so you will need to setup babel in your project (I suppose you did it because you're using ES6 anyway).

Then in AVA's setting, add this :

```
"ava": {
  ...
  "babel": "inherit"
}
```

It means that use your project babel setting to transpile the test dependencies. See more information in AVA docs: https://github.com/sindresorhus/ava/blob/master/docs/recipes/babelrc.md

Comment: Is this still relevant for AVA 1.x?

Answer (score 2):

Using [rweng](https://stackoverflow.com/users/974272/rweng), my solution came out a bit simpler.

1. `.babelrc`

```js
{
  "presets": [
    "es2015"
  ],
  "plugins": [
    "transform-runtime"
  ]
}
```

2. `package.json`:

```js
"ava": {
  "require": ["babel-register"],
  "babel": "inherit"
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately standard solution didn't work for my case.
Here is my solution which worked for ava + quasar + vue project

**.babelrc**

```
{
  "presets": [
    "es2017",
    "@ava/stage-4",
    "stage-3"
  ],
  "plugins": [
    "transform-runtime"
  ]
}
```

**package.json**

```
"ava": {
  "require": [
    "babel-register"
  ],
  "babel": "inherit"
},
"scripts": {
  "ava": "NODE_ENV=test ava",
  "test": "ava",
  "test:watch": "ava --watch --verbose"
}
```

**install modules**

```
yarn add babel-register babel-preset-es2017 @ava/babel-preset-stage-4 babel-plugin-transform-runtime babel-preset-stage-3 --dev
```