# Cannot get ava transpile to work with relatively-imported files

Tags: node.js, testing, babeljs, ava

The ES6 import works in this file, but generates an unexpected token `import` error when I'm importing relative files such as my Mongoose User model.

```
import mongoose from 'mongoose';
^^^^^^

SyntaxError: Unexpected token import
```

**.babelrc**

```
{
  "presets": [
    ["es2015", { "modules": false }]
  ],
  "plugins": [
    "transform-object-rest-spread",
    "transform-async-to-generator",
    "transform-export-extensions"
  ]
}
```

**package.json**

```
 "ava": {
    "require": [
      "babel-register"
    ]
  }
```

**users.test.js**

```
import test from 'ava'
import axios from 'axios'

import User from '../../models/user'
import { USER_REGISTRATION_ROUTES } from '../helpers/_test.properties.js'

test('user registration api works', async function (t) {
  const email = `test${Date.now()}@example.com`

  const userRegistrationData = {
    email,
    first_name: "john",
    last_name: "doe",
    password: "password"
  }

  await axios.post(USER_REGISTRATION_ROUTES, userRegistrationData)
    .then(response => {
      const data = response.data.data
      const user = data.user
      t.deepEqual(response.status, 200, 'Verify: response is successful')
      t.deepEqual(data.registered, true, 'Verify: user is registered')
      t.truthy(Object.keys(user).length > 0,
        'Verify: if registered, user object is returned')
      t.truthy(user.authentication_token,
        'Verify: token is generated on successful registration')
    })
    .catch((err) => {
      t.fail(`Cannot make requst to register user ${err}`)
    })

  User.remove({ email }, function (err) {
    if (err) {
      console.log('error')
    } else {
      console.log('success deleting test user')
    }
  })
})
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer that worked for me was the following suggested by [Serge Seletskyy](https://stackoverflow.com/users/781048/serge-seletskyy) [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36720335/ava-syntaxerror-unexpected-token-import). The `es2017` preset is required for ES2017 features such as async await.

**.babelrc**

```
{
  "presets": [
    "es2017",
    "@ava/stage-4",
    "stage-3"
  ],
  "plugins": [
    "transform-runtime"
  ]
}
```

**package.json**

```
"ava": {
  "require": [
    "babel-register"
  ],
  "babel": "inherit"
}
```

**install modules**

`yarn add babel-register babel-preset-es2017 @ava/babel-preset-stage-4 babel-plugin-transform-runtime babel-preset-stage-3 --dev`

Running `./node_modules/.bin/ava --verbose` should now work

Answer (score 0):

Don't think `import` is supported in nodejs yet. You have to use `require`.

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
```

Comment: that's what my `.babelrc` file is for? it's used during the webpack build process (which works) :/ and import works in the test file itself.

Answer (score 0):

Non-test files are loaded through `babel-register`, which applies your `.babelrc`. However you've disabled module transpilation. I see in another comment that you're using Webpack. Try adding a environment config for Babel which restores module transpilation. From the top of my head:

```
{
  "presets": [
    ["es2015", { "modules": false }]
  ],
  "plugins": [
    "transform-object-rest-spread",
    "transform-async-to-generator",
    "transform-export-extensions"
  ],
  "env": {
    "test": {
      "presets": [
        ["es2015", { "modules": true }]
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

This should work with the latest AVA version.

Answer (score 0):

My version of Ava is `1.0.0-beta.4`, and below is the solution that worked for me:

Add the following to your package.json

```
"ava": {
  "require": [
    "@babel/register"
  ]
}
```

Then `npm install --save-dev @babel/register`, and run test again.